# How do I create multiple script-daemons with zdaemon?

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I am using a script for log file analysis. This script is started as daemon, using zdaemon.
Jan Vlčinský wrote an excellen article about it here: http://ridingpython.blogspot.de/2011/08/turning-your-python-script-into-linux.html

Now I wanted to start a second script the same way, but I always encountered the following message:

```
WARNING! zdrun is managing a different program!
our program   = ['python', 'write_ips_from_asa_log_to_file.py']
daemon's args = ['python', '/home/pi/replace_ips_in_asa_log_w_hostnames_on_the_fly.py', '/var/log/asa.log', '/var/log/asa_w_hostnames.log']
daemon process already running; pid=2718
```

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick look at the help file shows that zdrun uses a default unix socket to start the program:

```
-s/--socket-name SOCKET -- Unix socket name for client (default "zdsock")
```

So you just have to define another socket name.

In this case I used:

```
sudo zdaemon -p "python write_ips_from_asa_log_to_file.py" -d -s ~/write_ips start
```

And it works!